# Why does DataFrame count method produces incorrect result when reading CSV with multiline rows?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV file with the following content

```
"","b","c"
"","""b","""c"
"","
b","c"
```

which I read with the following code:

```py
path = 'xyz.csv'
df = (
    spark.read
    .format('csv')
    .option('multiline', True)
    .option('escape', '\"')
    .load(path)
)
```

Running `df.head(5)` produces the expected result:

```
[Row(_c0=None, _c1='b', _c2='c'),
 Row(_c0=None, _c1='"b', _c2='"c'),
 Row(_c0=None, _c1='\nb', _c2='c')]
```

However:

```py
df.unpersist()
print(df.count())  # Output: 4

df.cache()
print(df.count())  # Output: 3
```

Why does `count` function produces incorrect result when DataFrame is not loaded into memory?